# How do I simply connect my microphone to python?

Tags: python

I've looked all over, but anything related to this question uses audio libraries. How do I connect python to my microphone?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: In what way? You'll either have to build your own library or use one that's been written. Can't just plug raw code into an audio device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to record your voice using your microphone that is connected to your computer, you can try the code below:

As mentioned in this article [playing-and-recording-sound-python](https://realpython.com/playing-and-recording-sound-python/#pyaudio)

*Pyaudio provides bindings for PortAudio, the cross-platform audio I/O library. This means that you can use pyaudio to play and record audio on a variety of platforms, including Windows, Linux, and Mac. With pyaudio, playing audio is done by writing to a Stream:*

```
import pyaudio
import wave

chunk = 1024  # Record in chunks of 1024 samples
sample_format = pyaudio.paInt16  # 16 bits per sample
channels = 2
fs = 44100  # Record at 44100 samples per second
seconds = 3
filename = "output.wav"

p = pyaudio.PyAudio()  # Create an interface to PortAudio

print('Recording')

stream = p.open(format=sample_format,
                channels=channels,
                rate=fs,
                frames_per_buffer=chunk,
                input=True)

frames = []  # Initialize array to store frames

# Store data in chunks for 3 seconds
for i in range(0, int(fs / chunk * seconds)):
    data = stream.read(chunk)
    frames.append(data)

# Stop and close the stream 
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
# Terminate the PortAudio interface
p.terminate()

print('Finished recording')

# Save the recorded data as a WAV file
wf = wave.open(filename, 'wb')
wf.setnchannels(channels)
wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(sample_format))
wf.setframerate(fs)
wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
wf.close()
```